# HTTP Proxy FOR Squid

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I have Squid set up on an Ubuntu server on my network, I can connect to Squid just fine. However, I need all traffic through Squid to be forwarded to a second proxy, how can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here:](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CacheHierarchy)

Essentially, what is required is to pretend that the forward proxy is another server in a "Cache Hierarchy".

So you need to add the following to your `Squid.Conf` file:

```
cache_peer parentcache.foo.com parent port 0 no-query default
never_direct allow all
```

That should get you going.